# Returning a value in a class function Which calls another class function

Tags: python, function, class

This is the code I'm trying to run, when I run it, I get a NameError 'area' is not defined.

```
from graphics import *
from circleinfoClass import *
import math

##

circle1 = circleInfo(10)

print(circle1.calculateArea())
print(circle1.calculateCircumference())
print(circle1.circleInfo())
```

Here is the sheet with my class :

```
from graphics import *
import math

class circleInfo:

    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def calculateArea(self):
        area = math.pi * (self.radius**2)
        return area

    def calculateCircumference(self):
        circumference = math.pi * 2 * self.radius
        return circumference

    def circleInfo(self):
        self.calculateArea()
        self.calculateCircumference()
        return 'Area is ', area, ' Circumference is ', circumference
```

I want to be able to call the two previous functions in the class, but I don't know how to return the values : `area` and `circumference`. I know it's very nooby and I'm probably missing something obvious,

Thanks guys.

Comment: `return ('Area is ' + str(self.calculateArea()) + ' Circumference is ' +  str(self.calculateCircumference()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the method to,

```
def circleInfo(self):
        area = self.calculateArea()
        circumference = self.calculateCircumference()
        return 'Area is ', area, ' Circumference is ', circumference
```

The problem is you are not collecting the results from `self.calculateArea()` and `self.calculateCircumference()` into the respective variables. Hence on the `return` line, it doesn't know what is `area` and `circumference`. Ergo the `NameError`

Comment: Thanks @han solo, I was thinking about this actually, but did not know how to write my code that way to get the answer, really appreciate it, Cheers!